# C Program To Generated Random Uppercase String and Replace Values

Tags: c, arrays, string, random, replace

First C programming class and beginning to learn programming. We are currently learning arrays in C and this is a learning task to help understand arrays and get a program that will create a random string of capital letters, then ask for user input of up to 20 uppercase letters, and then replace those letters within the previously random string generated with a *. I can get the random string to generate, however, I am having issues understanding what is the best way to pass that string to the second function to replace the selected values.

Brief Example:

Random string: AOIHGGDGIYGDYFDYIGDGPIGD

Enter letters to replace (up to 20 letters): GD

New string: AOIH****IY**YF*YI***PI**

Below is the code I have so far. Any advice on how and what part of the following code can be changed to achieve this is greatly appreciated!

Current partially erroneous output examples:

JOAUZKKMJVNDFABILLKAWNWEKUEJGHKRCBDUYYRG

Enter character to be replaced: W

Modified string after replacement is: Θi.

---

AKNZPUWCCKNOIQADOYXZIVCGFUWTKRQOGSWSPFFS

Enter character to be replaced: FSQ

Modified string after replacement is: Θi.

Thank you very much for your time and guidance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void getRandomStr();
void strreplace(char s1[], char chr, char repl_chr);

int main(int argc, const char argv[])
{


    char s1[41], s2, repl_chr;
    getRandomStr();
    printf("%c\n");

    gets(s1);
    printf("\nEnter character to be replaced: ");
    s2 = getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
    repl_chr = '*';
    printf("\nModified string after replacement is: ");
    strreplace(getRandomStr, s2, repl_chr);
    getch();
    return 0;



    return 0;
}


void getRandomStr(){


    char s1[41];
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++){

        char c = rand() % 26 + 'A';

        s1[i] = c;

    }

    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++){

        putchar(s1[i]);

    }

}

void strreplace(char s1[], char chr, char repl_chr)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s1[i] != '\0')
    {
          if (s1[i] == chr)
        {
          s1[i] = repl_chr;
        }
        i++;
    }
    puts(s1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: getRandomStr never nul terminates s1

Comment: The `s1` array in `getRandomStr` is not the same `s1` array that's declared in `main`. Using the same name in two different functions creates two separate, and unrelated, variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the commends, some of the problems in your code are:

- you do not null terminate the string in getRandomStr()
- you only take one character from the user instead of a whole string (you want to modify multiple chars, not just one)

I have modified your functions as follows:

```
void getRandomStr(char* s1);
void strreplace(char s1[], char chrs[], char repl_chr);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char s1[41];
    char s2[256], repl_chr;

    getRandomStr(s1);
    printf("%s\n", s1);

    //gets(s1);
    printf("\nEnter characters to be replaced: ");
    fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin);
    repl_chr = '*';

    printf("\nModified string after replacement is: ");
    strreplace(s1, s2, repl_chr);
    //getch();
    return 0;
}


void getRandomStr(char* s1){
    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++){
        char c = rand() % 26 + 'A';
        s1[i] = c;
    }
    s1[40] = '\0';
}

void strreplace(char s1[], char chrs[], char repl_chr)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (chrs[i] != '\0') {
        for (int j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++){
            if (s1[j] == chrs[i])
            {
                s1[j] = repl_chr;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    puts(s1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time!! This will greatly help me study these types of functions/code. I will use it for review and learning. :0)

Answer (score 0):

Final prog in case there ever is a need for something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 512


void getRandomStr(char s1[]);
void strreplace(char s1[], char chrs[], char repl_chr);
void check(char s2[], char chrs[]);
char cont(void);

int main(int argc, const char argv[]) {

    char s1[BUFF_SIZE];
    char s2[BUFF_SIZE], repl_chr;
    char proceed = 0;


    do {

    getRandomStr(s1);
    printf("Your random string is: %s\n", s1);


    /* gets(s1) */
    printf("\nEnter only 20 characters to be replaced: ");
    gets(s2, sizeof(s2), stdin);
    repl_chr = '*';

        check(s1, s2);


        printf("\nModified string after replacement is: ");
        strreplace(s1, s2, repl_chr);


    proceed = cont();

    } while (proceed == 'Y' || proceed == 'y');

}


void getRandomStr(char s1[]) {

    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {

        char c = rand() % 26 + 'A';
        s1[i] = c;

    }

    s1[40] = '\0';
}

void strreplace(char s1[], char chrs[], char repl_chr)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (chrs[i] != '\0') {

        for (int j = 0; s1[j] != '\0'; j++) {

            if (s1[j] == chrs[i])
            {

                s1[j] = repl_chr;

            }
        }

        i++;
    }
    puts(s1);
}


char cont()
{

    char proceed;
    printf("\nWould you like to run the program again (y/n)? ");
    scanf("%c%*c", &proceed);
    return proceed;
}

void check(char s2[], char chrs[])
{
    int i = 0;

    while (chrs[i] != '\0') {

        for (int j = 0; s2[j] != '\0'; j++) {

            if (!(chrs[i] >= 'A' && chrs[i] <= 'Z'))
            {

                printf("An invalid character was entered.\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```